# BlackBerry FileIO: Delete files with specific extension

Tags: file-io, blackberry, file-extension, delete-file

I'm working on a blackberry application which do some file handling, I would like to know how I can check a specific folder and delete only files with a specific extension. For example, I only want to delete my .log files.

Answer (score 1):

Please, spend some time studying the [FileConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html) API. It has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileConnection dir = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path);
Enumeration dirContent = dir.list("*.*", true);

FileConnection file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```